# Ginkgo Tree in south GA

Tags: diseases

Does anyone care to tell me what is going on to my young Ginkgo tree?(The leaves) The soil is quiet sandy if that helps you. I planted it this past April. It sits a little high for drainage purposes, [image]and I thought I dug a good size round hole for it then. ...Thank you all.